# Do rolling on all dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I would like to find in dataframe of prices all all-time highs in that were in history.

| timestamp | close | ath |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1234 | 0 |
| x | 2000 | 1 |
| x | 1956 | 0 |
| x | 1884 | 0 |
| x | 2234 | 1 |

So for specific row I would like to find a maximum for all previous rows and check if value in current row is greater than this maximum. I cannot do it without indexing for all rows and I know that it is inefficient.

Comment: What is your expected output? Is it the `ath` column?

Comment: Yes, it is the last column.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df['ath'] = df.groupby('timestamp')['close'].shift(1).lt(df['close']).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  timestamp  close  ath
0         x   1234    0
1         x   2000    1
2         x   1956    0
3         x   1884    0
4         x   2234    1
```

Comment: Thank you for answer - could you please explain shortly what you do here?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not give proper values if I checked it for whole dataframe

Comment: @FNTE maybe you need to show more of your dataframe? Try removing `.groupby('timestamp')` - `df['ath'] = df['close'].shift(1).lt(df['close']).astype(int)`

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, here is an alternative:

```
df['ath'] = (df['close'] > df['close'].expanding().max().shift()).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks, it gives good results.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cummax` to keep the highest seen value then shift rows and compare to the current row:

```
df['ath'] = df['close'].gt(df['close'].cummax().shift()).astype(int)
print(df)

# Output
  timestamp  close  ath
0         x   1234    0
1         x   2000    1
2         x   1956    0
3         x   1884    0
4         x   2234    1
```

Comment: Yeah, that's better than mine.

Comment: I think `expanding` is slower because you have to recompute the max at each iteration but the idea is good! +1